# How to ignore certain javascript libraries with the Html5 template?

Tags: javascript, configuration, ide, netbeans-7

I just upgraded my NetBeans from 7.3 Beta 2 to 7.3 RC1. In Beta 2 I could only exclude full folders (with the php project type). To ignore specific files I edited the project.properties file. This greatly helped me to ignore multiple versions of included libraries.

In RC1 we have the Html5 project type. I no longer find any option to ignore files, and adding ignore.path to the project.properties no longer seem to do the trick for me.

So my question is, is there a way to ignore files with the Html 5 project type? If so, how?

If not, is my only way of solving this to move the library sources outside of my project and include only the debug-all-with-comments type files, or how would you go about solving this problem with overly many versions of my libraries being parsed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partial solution can a migration from HTML5 to PHP Project in Netbeans.

1. Rename nbproject folder to nbproject-html in your Project source files folder to store netbeans settings.
2. Create Php Project with Existing Sources in Netbeans.
3. Go to Project - Properties - Ignored Folders - Add your libraries.

Now code completion is much faster. Moreover I could also solve the problem of documenting tags catch-up with Ctrl + Space, as php is evidently better supported in Netbeans than HTML5.

In our case it was netbeans 8 and pure javascript enterprise project based on ExtJS.

Comment: I'll read that answer as; "no, but you can fudge it", which was my conclusion as well. Thanks