# JavaScript on Netbeans Scarce Code Support Features

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse, netbeans, ide

I have difficulties coding in JavaScript with Netbeans. I can't see beforehand:

- my mistypes,
- relations between classes, functions and variables (dependency, parents-children etc.),
- javadocs references (both original and imported for libraries).

THE PROBLEM is in:

- heavy debugging because of primitive mistype and the use of irrelative substances;
- time consuming browsing to find help for the context.

I TRIED:

- Netbeans 7.4 (some basic Ctrl+Space lookup is supported, but very limited and usually useless);
- Eclipse 3.8 (no context support);

These IDEs provide adjustable autoformatting and text mark-up (braces, clever tabs, text colors etc.) This is all very helpful, but insufficient. After having to migrate from Java to JavaScript for job routines, I now understand how much work had I automized and saved coding Java. I just feel I'm missing Ctrl+Space after a dot for Javadoc and Ctrl+LeftClick to navigate to declaration. It results in more time creating similar things in code.

THE QUESTION IS:

- How to get JavaScript language docs for Netbeans?
- How to make Netbeans show relations between classes, variables and functions so that I don't see what can't be done from this context? For JavaScipt like it does for Java?

[Here](http://wiki.netbeans.org/JavaScript) are Netbeans JavaScript snapshots with everything that's needed. Where is that all? I don't see it in my IDE:

[image: No docs for JS Platform]
[image: No quick fixes and semantic checks]

[image: Type anything after a dot and get no error that no such method is allowed.]

Comment: The latest version of NetBeans supports java-script pretty well

Comment: webstorm is quite capable

Comment: Where are all these features, I don't see them in my 7.4 RC1 version (?): http://wiki.netbeans.org/JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

I can't add comments because i haven't reputation enough...

I am a Java developer since Java version 1.1, and Netbeans's truly fan since version 5.5 (Eclipse? What's that thing?).

I am currently developing Javascript code in Netbeans 7.4. It offers code completion exactly as it does with Java (plus javadoc-style documentation popup, Ctrl-Space behavior, colouring code...), almost the same pros and cons as developing java, php or another language...

And yes, it saves a lot of time of searching for object's methods and properties, misspelling...

> ---- Text added since your last editing some minutes ago....

OK, i know i'm not impartial, forgive me... Take a look to this, it may be helpful:

[Netbeans 7 HTML5 webapp javascript debugging](https://netbeans.org/kb/73/webclient/html5-js-support.html)

Maybe I don't know really what are you looking for, but in my opinion it is a good stuff. If you can debug an HTML5 webapp to such deep level...enough for me.

About the inline documentation in a javadoc-style, my NB shows a pretty nice one (bundled, i didn't plugged anything...). Of course, it could be more complete or functional... Take a look to this image:

[image: Netbeans 7.4 javascript development capture]

Next I'll try webstorm... Good luck!

> ---- More Text added .... jQuery documented API integration...

Ok, let's see how NB manages itself to show you a wonderful javadoc-style documentation popup of jQuery API...

[image: NB 7.4 full jQuery documentation in popup Ctrl-Space popup]

It looks so good to me... I love it :)

I only added the developer version of jQuery (the one commented and uncompressed) to the src folder of my opened Java project... nothing more... I think this is some kind of magic... Maybe you can add your own commented .js libraries in the same way. Just explore the jQuery .js to learn how to comment your code.

Just one more resource for you:
[Adding jQuery to your NB project](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/js-toolkits-jquery.html#addingjquery)

Comment: Netbeans 7.4 RC1 (some basic Ctrl+Space lookup is supported, but very limited and usually useless). In real code practically every function or parameter I Ctrl+Space gives No suggestions or Documentation not found. Not even a path to class and its parents. Also Ctrl+LeftClick does nothing. This is a team code and I sometimes don't know files and places substances are declared, but I can't navigate there. How do you do it all?

Comment: Maybe the trick is to switch from the Release Candidate (RC1) to the alfa bundle! Try to "double Ctrl-Space", i.e., "Ctrl-Space-Space"...

Comment: Thanks, +1 for discussion and to cheer up. :) Debugging is not generally such a big problem as its reasons. And Netbeans Connector is not always an option: I currently work on a team project using Mercurial with files stored remotely and Nebeans With Connector available browsers don't start, except for Embedded.

Comment: As for docs - yes there are and its encouraging. But I rarely see these basic functions in my code. Most things are customized and I'd like at least their type and path be detected. I also tried ExtJS library websource docs attached, but they are empty inline, though connected to IDE. Maybe you could help with it? WebStorm is also my nearest try I'll report afterwards.

Comment: I need the inline editor to give yo another tricky way... read my jQuery example!... I hope this will help you...

Answer (score 0):

I think, that you cannot expect the same level of tool support for Java (strongly typed, object oriented) and JavaScript (weakly typed, functional).
Compiler for strongly typed languages knows, what is allowed in given context, but in JavaScript is the situation drastically different. Everything is dynamic and you cannot tell what is mistype.

Anyway I think, that latest NetBeans 7.4 has really great support for JavaScript including code completion.

Comment: Anyway, JavaScript has some logics inside. It controls and reads itself fine. I just want it in line, like in Java. Netbeans and Eclipse provide adjustable autoformatting and text mark-up (braces, clever tabs, text colors etc.) This is all very helpful, but insufficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can see [here](http://www.ilovefreesoftware.com/14/featured/4-free-ide-for-javascript.html) for such IDE. Also you can take PhpStorm, Idea, WebStorm.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best IDE for JavaScript would be the JetBrains WebStorm. 
The company has also made IntelliJ Idea IDE for Java, which is in my humble opinion the best one available. 
You can download free version here: http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/

I'm using it a lot myself and I can really recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

Steps below helped me to partly resolve the problem:

- Changed project type from HTML5 to PHP to exclude libraries folders from code analysis as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22815355/1112963);
- Configured at Tools - Options - Editor - Hints - Javascript to "Suggest for current line" instead of "Warning".
- tune up and use correct tags for javadocs as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20650809/netbeans-jsdoc-not-displayed);
- Resolved proxy connection problems to make IDE see the Internet: Tools - Options - General;
- updated Netbeans to 7.4 from 7.4RC1;

Now you have:
 - fast code completion popup window load,
 - docs texts, including pop-up code completion docs for your own comments,
 - can navigate to declarations from other files Ctrl+LeftClick,
 - have suggestions on errors,
 - type recognition failing if you mistype function or variable name to smth impossible.